# Extremely blotchy stain - advice needed!

Tags: wood, staining

I'm genuinely at my wit's end. I'm using a dark oak oil stain on beech, and tested it on a spare bit of wood. I sanded the piece down to 240grit with an orbital sander before applying the stain. It looks *awful*.

I've tried using a pre stain conditioner before staining but it makes the colour extremely light.

[image: bad stain 1]
[image: bad stain 2]

For reference, I also tested the stain on another scrap bit, similarly coloured but an unknown wood type (though I'm guessing not beech) and it looks absolutely fine.

[image: nice stain]

Any advice would be extremely appreciated as I'm genuinely not sure what my options are at this point.

Comment: Hi, welcome to StackExchange. SE values prior research, did you do any? In addition to a *wealth* of information about staining and blotching out there online we have numerous prior Q&As on the topic here (you can see some of them in the 'Related' section (to the right if you're viewing the site on a computer). Two of the things prior research would have brought up for you is that sanding to 240 may be counterproductive, and that you should *always* finish sanding by hand in the direction of the grain (even if not staining, but especially when you are).

Comment: Kudos for doing tests! You'd be amazed the number of people who don't think to do this or can't be bothered (and then may be very disappointed by their results). Now re. your results, the included photos are really far too small (they open at the same size as the thumbnails) but *IF* I'm seeing what I think I am the reason you got two such dissimilar results in the test pieces is you used the stain on two completely different woods — a softwood in the first case, and maybe oak in the second case. These species (and beech) are *completely* unalike in all the ways that matter.

Answer (score 1):

> Any advice would be extremely appreciated as I'm genuinely not sure what my options are at this point.

I don't think I have the answers you're looking for, but maybe offering some thoughts will get your wheels turning.

1. If the pre-stain conditioner gives you a lighter finish than what you're after, that just means it's doing its job. Blotchy stain comes from some areas of the wood absorbing stain faster. The conditioner soaks into the wood first, slowing down the absorption in those areas and giving you a more even color. If you want a darker color, you can apply more stain and leave it on longer before wiping it off, or apply a second coat -- just recognize that the conditioner is going to slow things down.
2. A gel stain might be a good choice here. Gel stains are designed to sit mostly on the surface instead of soaking into the wood, so they can avoid that blotchy look.
3. It seems like you're on the right track: testing your finishing process on scraps until you're happy with the result is always a better idea than experimenting on your project. Just remember to keep trying. If you're not happy with this oil-based stain, try another product like a water based stain, gel stain, or aniline dye.

Good luck!